# Capture TCP-Packets with Python

Tags: python, pcap

I try to capture an HTTP-download with Python using dpkt and pcap. The code looks like

```
...
pc = pcap.pcap(iface)
for ts, pkt in pc:
    handle_packet(pkt)

def handle_packet(pkt):
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)

    # Ignore non-IP and non-TCP packets
    if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
        return
    ip = eth.data
    if ip.p != dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
        return

    tcp = ip.data
    data = tcp.data

    # current connection
    c = (ip.src, ip.dst, tcp.sport, tcp.dport)

    # Handle only new HTTP-responses and TCP-packets
    # of existing connections.
    if c in conn:
        handle_tcp_packet(c, tcp)
    elif data[:4] == 'HTTP':
        handle_http_response(c, tcp)
...
```

In `handle_http_response()` and `handle_tcp_packet()` i read the data of the tcp-packets (`tcp.data`) and write them to a file. However i noticed that i often get packets with the same TCP sequence number (`tcp.seq`) (on the same connection) but it seems that they contain the same data. Moreover it seems that not all packets are captured. For example if i sum up the packet-sizes the resulting value is lower than the one listed in the http-header (`content-length`). But in Wireshark i can see all packages.

Does anyone has an idea why i get those duplicate packets and how i can capture every packet belonging to the http-response?

**EDIT:**
Here you can find the complete code: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/25hYxgKi).
When running it prints something like that to stdout:

```
Waiting for HTTP-Audio-responses ...
...
New TCP-Packet, len=1440, tcp-payload=5107680, con-len=5197150 , dups=57 , dup-bytes=82080
New TCP-Packet, len=1440, tcp-payload=5109120, con-len=5197150 , dups=57 , dup-bytes=82080
New TCP-Packet, len=1440, tcp-payload=5110560, con-len=5197150 , dups=57 , dup-bytes=82080
----------> FIN <----------
New TCP-Packet, len=1937, tcp-payload=5112497, con-len=5197150 , dups=57 , dup-bytes=82080
New TCP-Packet, len=0, tcp-payload=5112497, con-len=5197150 , dups=57 , dup-bytes=82080
```

As you can see the TCP-payload plus the duplicate received bytes (5112497+82080=5194577) are lower than the filesize of the download (5197150). Moreover you can see that i receive 57 duplicate packages (same SEQ and same TCP-data) and that still packages are received after the packet with the FIN-flag.

So does anyone have an idea how i can capture all packets belonging to the connection? Wireshark sees all packets and i think it uses libpcap too.

I don't even know if i do something wrong or if the pcap-library does something wrong.

**EDIT2:**
OK, it seems that my code is correct: In Wireshark I saved the captured packets and used the capture-file in my code (`pcap.pcap('/home/path/filename')` instead of `pcap.pcap('eth0')`). My code read perfectly all packages (on multiple tests)! Since Wireshark uses libpcap too (afaik), i think the problem is the lib pypcap which does not provide me all packages.

Any idea on how to test that?

I already compiled pypcap by myself (trunk) but that didn't change anything -.-

**EDIT3:**
OK, I changed my code to work with pcapy instead of pypcap and have the same problem:
When reading the packets from a previous captured file (created with Wireshark) then everything is fine, but when I capture the packets directly from eth0 I miss some packets.

Interesting: When running both programs (the one using pypcap and the one using pcapy) in parallel they capture different packets. e.g. one programm receives one packet more.

But I have still no idea why -.-
I thought Wireshark uses the same base-lib (libpcap).

Please help :)

Comment: are you missing entire packets, or cutting packets short?  pcap has (used to have?) a small buffer by default, so you don't (didn't?) always get all the data for each packet.

Comment: That's an interesting question :) In Wireshark each TCP-packet has 1440 bytes data. The packets from pcap have 1440 byte data, too. The `content-length` of the download is 5197150. The sum of the TCP-packet-length is 5152510 (except duplicate packets with same SEQ as previous packets and without HTTP-header-information). The difference (5197150-5152510=44640) is (always) a multiple of 1440. So i think i miss entire packets, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of things to watch out for:

- make sure you have a big snaplen - for pcapy you can set it on open_live (second parameter)
- make sure you handle fragmented packets - this will not be done automatically - you need to check the details
- check statistics - unfortunately I don't think this is exposed to pcapy interface, but it's possible that you're not handling all packets; if you're too late you will not know that you missed something (although you can get the same information by tracking the length / position of tcp stream) libpcap itself does expose those statistics, so you might be able to add the function for it

Comment: THX for your reply. To 1) When using pcapy i used a maximum snaplen of 2097100, but nothin changed. (2097101 causes a buffer overflow) To 2) I think you mean IP packet fragmentation?! I changed my code to analyse the IP-packets. But no packet had the MORE_FRAGMENTS-flag set to 1. Just a handful of packets had the "Don't Fragment"-flag set to 0 but these packets are too small for being the missing packets ;)

Comment: @Biggie Actually, please limit the snaplen to 1500 (or whatever your actual mtu is). The capture buffer is split into snaplen-sized chunks. That means if you have the snaplen set too big, you won't be able to buffer many packets - as the capture buffer has a fixed size.

Comment: My router uses a MTU of 1492. When i used 1492 as snaplen i noticed, that the data-length of each tcp-packet was only 1416 (same with a snaplen of 1500). So i increased the snaplen until i get a data-length of 1440 (as before). My current snaplen is 1517 and actually i sometimes receive all packets ... but not always -.- With a snaplen of 1700 i receive all packets more often but still not always. Is there a way to find out which snaplen should be used to always get all packets?

Comment: It should be >= mtu (actually it should be == mtu, but I noticed some packets are not caught in that case... which should not happen as far as I understand, but did in testing) 151x should be optimal - anything higher will cause the buffer to be filled up quicker than necessary - and you really want it to stay empty. If you capture something that is really high speed this paper may be interesting for you: Improving Passive Packet Capture: Beyond Device Polling (http://luca.ntop.org/Ring.pdf) and check the PF_RING in general.

Comment: With a snaplen of "151 * MTU" i only get ca. 95% of packets of each download. Now i set the snaplen to "2 * MTU" (2*1492=2984) and in 30+ test cases only one download was not completely captured. Even though a snaplen of 2984 works good for me, how can i make sure, that it works on other computers/networks too? Which snaplen is Wireshark using? Since Wireshark gets alwayws all packets.

Answer (score 0):

Set the snaplen to 65535. Apparently this is the default for Wireshark:
http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html