# How to sniff HTTP packets in python?

Tags: python, http, sniffer

I want to sniff all the HTTP packets in my computer via python(version2.6.. is this possible? can I do it with scapy, or without other external modules?

Comment: Concerning to closing votes, I think this is a good question. He's asking for a technique to solve a particular problem, what's the problem?

Comment: Did you look at this? (quickly before this question gets closed...) http://wiki.wireshark.org/Python

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Request and Response Inspection with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663379/http-request-and-response-inspection-with-python)

Comment: Related: [Packet sniffing in Python (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/462439/95735)

Answer (score 7):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is only for extracting data from webpages or similar structured documents.

To actually read the packets coming from the NIC your best performance option would probably be to use a C/C++ API that has python bindings.

For example WireShark has a [Python API](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Python).

[Pcapy](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy) is a module for packet capture using libpcap.

[LibPCAP](http://www.tcpdump.org/index.html) is the packet capture library written for TCPDUMP and also used in WireShark.

Another option is to try the dpkt python module. Here is a nice [write up](http://www.commercialventvac.com/dpkt.html).
Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155050/capture-tcp-packets-with-python) using using dpkt and pcap to sniff HTTP packets.

**EDIT**: oops, I misread scapy. Thanks root!

As you mentioned, [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html) is another python module that also uses LibPCAP.
This [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sniffing) has an example of sniffing.

If you are having trouble running on Python 2.7 check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447461/running-scapy-on-windows-with-python-v2-7-enthought-python-distribution-7).

Comment: It seems that the Python API for WireShark is gone now. PyShark seems like the most active approach to this now, as noted in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark

Python wrapper for `tshark`

Usage:

```
>>> capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='eth0')
>>> capture.sniff(timeout=50)
>>> capture
<LiveCapture (5 packets)>
>>> capture[3]
<UDP/HTTP Packet>

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
    print 'Just arrived:', packet
```

Answer (score 2):

**pypcap**,https://code.google.com/p/pypcap/  simplified object-oriented Python extension module for libpcap - the current tcpdump.org version, the legacy version shipping with some of the BSD operating systems, and the WinPcap port for Windows.This is a Windows version.And if you are using #nix,just install **pcap** and **dpkt** module.

Comment: OK, if I want to use the dpkt & pcap modules for the sniffing, how can I sniff with them HTTP packets? I will be glad to get for an example..
I saw an example how to sniff with this modules an icmp packets but not HTTP packets..

Answer (score 0):

FTR, Scapy will support HTTP packets starting from 2.4.3:
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html

```
>>> HTTPRequest().show()
###[ HTTP Request ]###
  Method= 'GET'
  Path= '/'
  Http_Version= 'HTTP/1.1'
  A_IM= None
  Accept= None
  Accept_Charset= None
  Accept_Datetime= None
  Accept_Encoding= None
  [...]
```

Sniff demo:

```
from scapy.layers.http import * # read the doc
from scapy.sendrecv import sniff
sniff(lfilter=lambda x: HTTP in x, prn=lambda x: x.summary())
```