# Get Form Data over Network

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x

I want to make a program that will get form data. So whenever anybody on a local network submits form data to a website, I would like to see that data being submited. Is this possible? If it is, is it possible in python? Thank you.

Comment: Wait. Do you mean you want a programs that spies on people on your local network?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, you want to listen for packets on the local network and filter out everything but POST (which would be submitting form data). If I were you, I would look into wireshark, capture all the packets, filter out all that aren't POST to the specific website.

Wireshark has a [Python API](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Python), and you may find [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906308/how-to-sniff-http-packets-in-python) of interest.

Hope I helped a little.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) as it is easy to setup and may address your core needs. Bonus, it's pretty easy to set up across devices.

**Disclaimer** - if you are doing this without the knowledge or consent of those on your network, you're likely breaking the law.