# How to sniff 802.11 management frames for fields

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to use **`Scapy`** to output the mac, ssid & rssi. I've tried the following but all I get back are question marks. The **`Scapy`** documentation is pretty dry, I'm having a hard time understanding it.

```
sniff(iface="mon0", prn=lambda x:x.sprintf("{%Dot11ProbeReq:%RadioTap.dBm_AntSignal%\t}"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sniff HTTP packets in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906308/how-to-sniff-http-packets-in-python) Note the comment about "Scrapy" only being useful for webpages

Comment: @DrColossos That really isn't related, but the tags had been very wrongly (and misleadingly) edited, causing the confusion.

Comment: @Cukic0d, ah now it makes sense... only looked at the tags and misread the name "Scapy". Thank you for clarification!